# BlackBerry 10 : Application not installing on device?

Tags: blackberry-10, native-code

While installing sample app on my device (Blackberry Q10) its giving me error like `Deployment failed:Info:Sending Request:Install and Launch...`.

Please find screenshot of error message in this link :

http://www.500images.com/uploads/914164013ErrorMsg.png

Appreciate if you could have any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add some information: Did you install the developper certificate on your device ? Release or debug ? SDK Version ?

Comment: The package name contains testDev, it's a debug build. Don't know for other questions…

Comment: One more question, by the way: is this your first install attempt, or an upgrade? I mean, is your app (or an older build of it) already installed on the device?

Comment: My SDK version is 10.1.0.1020. I think it seems that my SDK version is lower than the sample which is not installing into my device, might be it developed in other SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to resolve this personally by:

1. Removing existing copies of the app on the device, then trying again
2. Rebooting the device

John